# OData paging with skip and top - how to know that there is no more data?

Tags: odata

I have OData source, that implements `$skip` and `$top` parameters. 
There are x number of entities that are returned. Say, I have only 250 entities. And then I try to do the paging like this:

```
https://example.com/EntitySet?$top=30&$skip=220
```

If my skip goes beyond the number of total entities, I eventually get timeout from service.

**Is there a parameter or data, that would inform me that there are no more items?** Is there something that can/should be implemented on OData side, that gets returned instead of timeout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For OData 2.0 and OData 3.0 protocols:
You should use: `$inlinecount=allpages`

> [http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products$inlinecount=allpages&$top=5&$format=json](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=5&$format=json)
>
> Identifies the first 5 Product Entries and
>   includes a count of the total number of Product Entries.

For OData 4.0, you can read the **nextLink** annotation embeded in the response. (See example [here](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#entitySet))

> **4.5.5 Annotation odata.nextLink** The odata.nextLink annotation indicates that a response is only a subset of the requested collection
>   of entities or collection of entity references. It contains a URL that
>   allows retrieving the next subset of the requested collection.

Answer (score 5):

If you add `&$count=true` to your uri the service will include a total count in the response. The json response will include a `"@odata.count"` property. This property indicates the total number of entities.

That way you can check if you've received all entities.

Comment: How do you retrieve the value of @odata.count on the client side if you are using Microsoft ODATA Client Proxy in VS 2017.

Comment: If I'm able to tell ODATA MS Client to include the Total Count by using IncludeTotalCount() method on DataServiceQuery, there must be a way to retrieve that value? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @IftikharAli You are right, I think it is explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ee474390(v=vs.103).aspx), see the example for how to access the result. (I have not tried this myself)