# How do I use pagination in requests

Tags: python, api, pagination, python-requests, odata

Every time I run my code I get `250` records from the API. 250 is stored in `max_records`. The maximum amount of records is `1429`. `1429` is stored in `total_records`. I want to extract the data in pieces of `250` till I reach `1429`.

**This is my code:**

```
response1 = requests.get('https://***-***-***.***.com/odata/***', headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies)

data = response1.json()

next_link = data['@odata.nextLink']
total_records = data['@odata.count']
max_records = next_link[313:]


while max_records is not total_records:
    n_response = requests.get(next_link, headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies)
    if max_records == total_records:
        break
```

**When I run above code I get the following error:**
`MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool............`

Comment: We don't know which API you use, so we can't help much. That being said, I think the issue comes from the API itself and not your code. Try perhaps to search in the API documentation if they support some kind of pagination.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the API, its more about the code. I need an example about auto paging

Answer (score 0):

You can get the concept from this JavaScript function,

Note that I send the number of records **(take=20 , skip=0)** parameters to server side and process it to get them from DB,

Then send the next **(take=20 , skip=20)** , it will give me the next 20 records, and so on.

simple function:

```
function loadRecords(skip = 0, take = 20) {
                            $.getJSON('api url', {                           
                                skip: skip,
                                take: take
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                console.log(data);//data to be viewed
                            });                                
                          };
```

more advanced:

```
 function loadRecords(skip = 0, take = 20) {
                            var d = new $.Deferred(); 
                            $.getJSON('api url', {                           
                                skip: skip,
                                take: take
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                d.resolve(data);
                            });
                            return d.promise();
                          };
```

Comment: It seems very complex to change this JavaScript file to a Python file?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there is a field `@odata.nextLink` until the last page.

I suggest to use a generator and a Session to do paging which also might help with the `MaxRetryError` you're getting.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

def paging():
    url = 'https://***-***-***.***.com/odata/***'
    page = session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies).json()
    yield page

    next_url = page.get('@odata.nextLink')
    while next_url:
         page = session.get(next_url, headers=headers, params=params1, proxies=proxies).json()
         yield page
         next_url = page.get('@odata.nextLink')

for page in paging():
    # process page
```

You might need to construct the URL again as `'@odata.nextLink'` is probably relative to the URL, not absolute.

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259251/1344855) also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644311/1344855).

Comment: I dont' have a page parameter, or maybe I don't know where to find it.

Comment: I can assure you that I dont have a page parameter.

Comment: what do you mean by `process page`

Comment: I did `for page in paging(): print(page)` and I received the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`

Comment: is it possible to chat with each other?